# Passing inputs from parent document to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I have an iframe embedded on the main page of my project whose `src` is changed to different HTML templates with the same input ids `(id="name1")`, these sources are "first.html" and "second.html" and are hosted on the same server (there shouldn't be any Same Origin issues).

The code for the first.html is:

```
<p>A common computer greeting is: <input type="text" name="display" id="name1"/></p>
```

The code for second.html is:

```
<p>People frequently use the phase: <input type="text" name="display" id="name1"/></p>
```

I have uploaded sample code on jsfiddle (this code works when the src is about:blank and I am just writing directly to the iframe): http://jsfiddle.net/EdwardMoseley/x6gqk7qb/

```
Field1: <input type="text" id="field1" value="Hello World!"><br>
<iframe src="about:blank" name="myFrame"></iframe>
<button type="button" onclick="writeToFrame();">Try it!</button>
<script>
function writeToFrame() {
var iframe = window.frames["myFrame"].document;
iframe.open();
iframe.write(document.getElementById("field1").value);
iframe.close();
}
</script>
```

I tried to adapt this to my situation by using the following code:

```
function writeToFrame() {
var iframe = window.frames["myFrame"].document;
iframe.open();
iframe.write(iframe.getElementById("name1").value = document.getElementById("field1").value);
iframe.close();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I click the button to call the function, the iframe disappears.

Any ideas? If you have any questions or would like any clarification please just let me know.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: don't use `write` it will wipe out the page. Use onload event callback of iframe to do any manipulation from parent window ( elements have to exist before you can interact with them). You should be able to find numerous tutorials and posts about interacting with iframes by doing a web search

Comment: `iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("name1").value = ...` ??? Just wondering, why this question has been tagged with jQuery?